# How to manually create and close google analytics session in a react-native app?

Tags: session, react-native, google-analytics

I am using react-native-google-analytics-bridge in my react native application. I want to create a google analytics session when user logs in and close it when user logs out. I could not find any related information in the react-native-google-analytics-bridge documentation. (https://github.com/idehub/react-native-google-analytics-bridge)
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it for android
At this moment react-native-google-analytics-bridge has no sessionControl api. To add that Find below files inside react-native-google-analytics-bridge folder

GoogleAnalyticsBridge.java and add

```
@ReactMethod
public void createNewSession(String trackerId, String screenName) {
    Tracker tracker = getTracker(trackerId);
    tracker.setScreenName(screenName);
    tracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().setNewSession().build());
}
```

GoogleAnalyticsTracker.js and add

```
createNewSession(screenName) {
  GoogleAnalyticsBridge.createNewSession(this.id, screenName);
```

}

GoogleAnalyticsBackwardsCompatibility.js and add 
`createNewSession(screenName) {
    this.tracker.createNewSession(screenName);
  }`

RCTGoogleAnalyticsBridge.m (adding only the signature for ios) and add
`RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(createNewSession:(NSString *)trackerId screenName:(NSString *)screenName)
{
}`

go inside react-native-google-analytics-bridge/android folder and clean by using "./gradlew clean command"

then from react-native-google-analytics-bridge folder build with the changes made using "npm run start"